# Insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group

Tags: android-studio, debugging, usb, usb-debugging

here is the error message I have got:

Error 1 retrieving device properties for 0001927R10001ED2:
adb: insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information

Launching lib/homepage/homepge.dart on 0001927R10001ED2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
adb: insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
Error launching application on 0001927R10001ED2.

I just want to run my application on my android phone using usb debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "usb debugging" in the developer options of your phone?
This might help setting things up:
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options